# Extract data with Google Analytic Reporting API v4 in python without credentials jon file?

Tags: python, pandas, google-analytics-4

I'm new to Google Analytic Reporting v4.
Because I don't have the permission to create my own credentials/api key for this. So is there a way to authenticate GA4 Api in Google Colab without using creds.json file?

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

This was the way of authentication I use and get data from Bigquery using a pandas built-in function: `pd.io.gbq.read_gbq`

Is possible for me to do the same thing for pulling data from Google Analytics?